# Send message to mobile through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I am new in javascript i want to send a message to mobile using javascript
In PHP this can be done by this code

```
$number = 'your-number';

$url = "http://pointsms.in/API/sms.php?username=[xxxxxx]&password=[xxxxxx]&from=[xxxxxxxx]&to=[xxxxxxxxxx]&msg=[xxxx]&type=1&dnd_check=0";

fopen($url, 'r');
```

But i am using the opencart and i want to perform this action using the javascript

In javascript i am using the window.location to open the url in in window 
but i don't want to open in window

```
window.location.replace('http://pointsms.in/API/sms.php?username=[xxxxxx]&password=[xxxxxx]&from=[xxxxxxxx]&to=[xxxxxxxxxx]&msg=[xxxx]&type=1&dnd_check=0');
```

Please help to solve this problem

Comment: Problem and desired behavior are not clear. Try to enhance your question

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX.

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using ajax can you please specify how this can be done using the ajax code

Answer (score 0):

AJAX

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'http://pointsms.in/API/sms.php?username=[xxxxxx]&password=[xxxxxx]&from=[xxxxxxxx]&to=[xxxxxxxxxx]&msg=[xxxx]&type=1&dnd_check=0', true)
xhr.send()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this produce error   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pointsms.in/API/sms.php?username=[xxxxxx]&password=[xxxxxx]&from=[xxxxxxxx]&to=[xxxxxxxxxx]&msg=[xxxx]&type=1&dnd_check=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.